# How should i center horizontally a div without width?

Tags: html, css, centering

I'm still very new to CSS, but I tried different solutions on stackoverflow, but none seems to work.

Here is the parent div : (existing application, so i can't control the inline style, hence the use of !important)

```
element.style {
    display: block;
    height: 662px;
    width: 1460px;
}
#ModalScroll{
    position:fixed !important;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:1001; 
    height:1px;
    width:1px;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:none;
    font-size:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Child div :

```
element.style {
    display: block;
    left: 470px;
    margin-top: 150.5px;
    top: 315px;
    width: 500px;
}

.ModalDialog{
    border:1px solid #3C4749;
    background-color:#FFF;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    display:none;
    position:absolute !important;
    font-size: 12px;
    top: 0px !important;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    text-align: center; 
    vertical-align: middle;
```

The div can have different widths, it's perfectly centered vertically but i can't do it horizontally.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: I don't get the downvoting, i'm new to CSS and tried to provide you by as much information as i can. I can't make a jsfiddle because it's a huge application, and i can't reproduce what's existing.

Comment: Can you draw a picture or something then? Its hard to follow.

Comment: Do you only have access to the css or can you modify the html or add some javascript?

Comment: Which div are you trying to center, the parent or the child?

Comment: I only have access to the css, yes. The inline style is not helping either.
I'm trying to center the child div. It's a dialog box that got triggered when you want to delete something for example.

Comment: Does the width of the child element ever change?

Comment: Yes it does, i just posted the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the rather simple solution, i just had to add in the child div:

```
{
...
    right: 0px !important;
    left : 0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with position:absolute and the translate trick :

```
yourDiv{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Can you please post a fiddle ?

Comment: As i told the other users, i only have access to the css.

Answer (score -1):

This can also centralise an element (that has a width)

```
{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```